# UIScrollView with touch interceptor for contentSize to control subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

assume I've got the following view hierarchy;

[image]

Those views are actually ShinobiCharts, which are subclasses of UIView. View1 acts as a main chart that can be touched by the user (pinch, pan, long press and so on). This view in turn controls the other views (View2, View3 and so on) with regards to specific, touch dependent properties (the user pans the View1, so views 2 and 3... have to act accordingly and pan as well).
However, once the user scrolls the UIScrollView, View1 may disappear from the screen, leaving only views 2, 3 etc. visible, which don't have the corresponding gesture recognizers, so the user can't interact with the charts any more, bad user experience.
I sure could add recognizers to these additional charts as well, but during pinch, that would mean that both fingers would have to be located within a single view, the user can't just touch where he wants in order to pinch and zoom, again, bad user experience.

To cut things short, I need some sort of touch interceptor that covers the entire content area of the UIScrollView so that when a user pinches or pans, the corresponding touches will be forwarded to the main chart (View1) which in turn can update the other subviews.
Vertical scrolling the UIScrollView should be possible at all times.

**First experiment:**

I've tried adding a transparent UIView to the ViewController that covers the UIScrollView.
However, even with a direct reference to View1, the touches wouldn't get forwarded.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.chartReference touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I'm not so sure if this is the correct way to achieve this anyways.

**Second experiment:**

Disabling userInteraction on the chart subviews in UIScrollView and add my own pinch and pan gestures (in UIViewController) to the UIScrollView.

Issues;
 1. The UIScrollView doesn't scroll any more. 
 2. How to forward these gestures to View1?

I'm afraid I can't provide more example code at this point since there isn't really much relevant code to show yet.

**Edit:**
Small note to experiment two;
The gesture recognisers have been added as follows;

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGesture:)];
pinchGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];
```

Simultaneous gesture recognition on the UIViewController has been enabled;

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
```

}

**Edit:**

Problem 2 for experiment 2 has been solved. I didn't set the correct delegate for the pan/pinch gestures. D'oh!

What remains is how to forward the pinch/pan gestures.

Comment: Did you try the `UIScrollView` zoom functionality. It supports by default pinch to zoom, you just have to provide the view that will be zoomed, so I think you just have to determine which view is on screen and pass it to the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Zooming in UIScrollView seems more like a solution to simply zoom subViews of UIScrollView, hence modifying their sizes. That's not what I'm looking for though. The sizes have to remain constant as only the content of the my UIViews need to change, which in turn is handled by the ShinobiChart itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close with placing a transparent view on top of the others. But, you need to override one more method.

You want to override hitTest:withEvent on the transparent view. This method is used while traversing the responder chain to see which view handles a touch in a particular area. If a view handles that touch, it returns Itself. If it wants to pass it on to the next view below it, it returns nil. If it knows another view handles that touch, it can return that view.

So, in your case, if the point is in the target area of your top transparent view, you return view1. View1's gesture recognizer should then be called.

**Example**:

InterceptorView is a transparent view which lies on top of the scrollView.  TargetView is a view inside the scrollView, and has a TapGestureRecognizer attached to it.

```
class InterceptorView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var targetView1: UIView?

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("[Interceptor] Testing point: \(point) ")
        if self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
            println("Hit")
            return targetView1
        }
        else {
            println()
            return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
class TargetView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

     @IBAction func handleGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)
        print("[TargetView] Got gesture.  Location \(location) ")
        if (pointInside(location, withEvent: nil)) {
            println("Inside");
        }
        else {
            println("Outside");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the project:
https://github.com/annabd351/GestureForwarding

(there's some other stuff in there too, but it works!)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. View1 doesn't receive the touches. Is it possible that UIScrollView blocks them?

Comment: I just tried it putting an "Interceptor" view on top of the scrollView.  Seems to work -- I made an example project.  (see edited answer)

Comment: Your project on Github doesn't contain any source code. My code does look exactly like yours though, and in fact, does work in a way that touchesBegan/Moved are getting called in a subclass of TargetView (I can't directly change TargetView as it is part of a third party library. The thing is, I need the TargetView to pick up gestures, which won't work with this method of touch forwarding, or at least, not with the code provided right now.

Comment: Ooops!  Ok, the source is there now. I think the difference is that I'm explicitly creating another gesture recognizer (via the storyboard, in this case), and attaching it to the targetView.  I'm not sure where touchesBegan is called in the responder chain, but gesture recognizers skip the responder chain altogether.  So, they pick up everything.  (I think... I'm still a little hazy on it myself)  Check out the source (now that it's actually there!)

Comment: Ok then, additional gesture recognizers in my TargetView are getting called as well, just like in your example. The problem now is that TargetView's superview (ShinobiChart) doesn't pick them up. Setting ShinobiChart directly instead of using a subclass has the same effect. Well, I guess this is an issue specific to this very control, right? I mean for custom classes the gestures are being picked up properly, so your answer is in fact correct. Thanks for that. From here on I guess I'll have to get back to the guys over at shinobicontrols.

Comment: Thanks Anna. I'll keep my original question updated as soon as I got a solution to this. For everyone else with custom target classes they've got control over, the solution Anna provided here works properly.

Comment: Finally, done fixing this issue. The problem was indeed with the Shinobi chart eating up the gestures. The solution is to disable panning and zooming gestures on the chart and adding gesture recognizers to the UIScrollView.

Comment: That does *not* sound like it was fun to debug. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Oh you have no idea! :) Thanks again for your help, Anna.